# How to get Git Pull Requests and CI Build Trigger to work together in VSTS?

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request, azure-pipelines

So here is what I'm trying to setup.

1. I have a CI build that builds anytime master path * is changed. 
   This works fine until

[image]

2. I have a Git Pull Request policy that does Gated builds, then #1 CI build stops triggering after the pull request is completed (if you check the checkbox in red it makes git do a "Gated" build).

[image: VSTS Screenshot]

I want #1 to publish nuget packages and #2 does not, so they are using two different build definitions.

Please how can I make this work?

As an aside note [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers) is the way to do it if I were using TFS as my version control.

[image: VSTS screenshot]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Git doesn't support Gated Check-in. You're looking at a build definition that's using TFVC for version control, so pull requests don't enter into it.

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect what I'm asking and explain what I mean by a "Gated" git checkin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :)  Currently VSTS is experiencing issues with CI triggers.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/06/27/ci-builds-may-not-trigger-as-expected-627-investigating/

Comment: In that case it's probably better to delete this question.